# Koudoku controller not visible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using [Koudoku](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku) for a payment/subscription wall. I get a ruby syntax error from the `subscription_controller`:

```
NoMethodError in Koudoku::SubscriptionsController#show
undefined method `can?' for #<Koudoku::SubscriptionsController:0x00007fab279983b8>
Extracted source (around line #57):
55
56
57
58
59
60

      # also, if cancan methods are available, we should use that to authorize.
      if defined?(:can?)
        return unauthorized unless can? :manage, @subscription
      end

      return @subscription.present? ? @subscription : unauthorized
```

I can't see the controller inside my project (it was generated by koudoku). Rails action debug controller says the file is located at:

```
koudoku (2.0.0) app/controllers/koudoku/subscriptions_controller.rb:57:in `load_subscription'
```

but there is no koudoku folder inside my project and also no `subscriptions_controller`.

Any ideas why this is so? Any ideas?

Comment: No method error is not a syntax error. If there is a syntax error, the program cannot even be parsed, and hence cannot be executed at all.

Comment: It doesn't say that the error is from `subscription_controller`, it says it's from `subscriptions_controller`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku/issues/188) of the gem. It looks like it uses the [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem but it doesn't actually check if the gem is even loaded, or at least not properly.

Try to install the CanCan gem or the more recent one [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and check if it works then.

```
$ gem install cancancan
$ rails g cancan:ability
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the issue immediately.